# Detecting isolation/segregation in classroom data

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

Suppose we have two groups of students: `A` and `B`.

We want to look at the distribution of these two groups of students in each classroom in a school district by grade (e.g., *3rd*) and subject (e.g., *math*) to determine whether or not group `A` students are being isolated from group `B` students in that subject and grade level.

*Stated statistically, is a significantly larger group `A` vs. `B` students is found in each classroom?*

For example, here are the distribution of these two groups of students in Classrooms 1, and 2, in Grade 3, Math:

```
# Classroom 1:
 A  B
30  5

# Classroom 2:
A   B
26  4
```

**Question:** What statistical test can help answering the question above? Is there any additional data needed for such a test? (A possible `R` solution is appreciated.)

***Note:*** I think a [one-way chi-square test of good fit](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test-in-r), could do this but I'm unsure if additional info. might be needed (e.g., probabilities of `A` or `B`).

Comment: Would it make sense to test against a null hypothesis that for Group A, the distribution of students is 50%-50% in Classroom 1 and Classroom 2 ?

Comment: The phrase "intentionally ... grouped together" is troublesome for several reasons.  The first is that your data will provide no information about intention.  The second is your data will provide no information about grouping in many cases depending on how $A$ and $B$ are defined.  The third is that "grouped together" has only a vague meaning.  What do you want it to mean and how do you measure grouping?

Comment: @whuber, By "intentionally", I mean systematically/statistically beyond what can be attributed to chance or randomness. Think of group A as students of color, group B as other students. By "grouped togher", I mean a statistically significant difference in the composition of each classroom with respect to these two groups of students. Please let me if any additional pieces of data are needed to achieve my goal.

Comment: @whuber, further clarifying on "grouped together", I mean statistically larger group 'A' vs. group 'B' students found in each classroom.

Comment: What "statistically larger" might mean is unclear.  In your example, because group A is far more *numerous* than group B, it's almost inevitable that it will be more numerous within each classroom.  If you are trying to ask whether the data are consistent with a model in which 56 A's and 9 B's are randomly distributed into two classrooms, then Fisher's Exact Test will help.  Since it sounds like you plan to perform such testing repeatedly, bear in mind the multiple comparisons issue.

Comment: @whuber, your latest comment is very insightful. Would you kindly be able to post a formal answer (possibly including your emphasis on issues with repeated testing)?

Comment: How many classrooms do you have ?  And how many groups of students ?  And then, how many subjects (e.g. math) ? and how many grades ?  ....  The next question is, do you want a simple solution (like conducting a chi-square goodness of fit on each subject/grade combination (Or each group of students ?  I don't really understand which makes sense in your case.) ?  Or would you rather a larger model, where you can tease out e.g.  the differences in Math across grades ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico, thank you so much for the comments (sorry for the thanksgiving delay in my response). **Short answer:** I'm open to both solutions especially your second solution. **Long answer:** In my data, I have classes arranged by their courses. For example, I have 26 `algebra I` classes and then 23 `Geometry` classes in our district of . In each of these classes, I have students categorized by groups `A` vs. `B`.  So I  would be open to both solutions. Would you like to offer thoughts or R code for the second solution?. . .

Comment: @SalMangiafico, . . .,  Also regarding the first solution, is it a problem if group `A` (students of color) are naturally found in lower number than that of group `B` (other students)? I ask this because if the population of group `A` are naturally smaller than that of group `B`, that should affect the inferential conclusions we make, correct?

Comment: I'm not going to venture a complete answer. 1) I suspect there is some way to use logistic regression with *A/B* being the dependent variable, and using the theoretical proportion of *A/B* as a test of the coefficients (rather than using *A/B* = 1 as the null hypothesis.  But I don't know how to do this.  2) It may be simplest to use a binomial test (or chi-square goodness-of-fit test) for any relevant class.  That is, the proportion of *A/B* in *Algebra*;  the proportion of *A/B* in *Geometry*; and so on.